# Why are sum types called sum types?

Tags: algebraic-data-types, discriminated-union

In the course of learning Haskell I read about Algebraic Data Types, sum types and product types. While product types are analogous to the Cartesian product and "product" immediately made sense to me I don't understand why sum types (aka variant types aka tagged union aka discriminated union aka disjoint union) are called *sum* types.

Wikipedia says:

> The sum type corresponds to intuitionistic logical disjunction under
>   the Curry–Howard correspondence.

OK, I get it: Disjunction is analogous to OR in boolean algebra and this kind of looks like sums because

```
 OR |   | +
-----------
0 0 | 0 | 0 
0 1 | 1 | 1
1 0 | 1 | 1
1 1 | 1 | 0 (mismatch here)
```

But it does not really fit because of 1 + 1.

I found various explanations on what product and sum types are and I think I get it. The sum type is either one thing *OR* the other thing.

**But why exactly is it called sum type?** Just because it is a convention to use the symbol + for the OR operator? Or because "Sum types are the dual of product types."?

(Again, unless I missed something big, please don't explain sum/product type. I think I get the concept. I only want to know why it is called *sum* type.)

Comment: Type Summing can also be called Type Merging (original idea of K.HARISAI).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's called a sum type because the *number of values* of `A + B` is the sum of the number of values of `A` and `B`.

Comment: Ooooh, that makes sense.

Comment: More generally, set disjunction _is_ summation for sets. Similarly, product types' (ie. structs) set of component values is the set product of their component types' values.